# Что делать если модератор не прав и при этом грубит?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация

Я задал вопрос у которого @Dmitriy Simushev убирает теги. Я естественно объяснил ему свое и единственное верное видение это проблемы, но он начал грубить. После этого я попросил дать ссылку, где бы я мог решить этот спор, но он начал удалять эти сообщения.

Я не хочу показаться грубым, но по факту модератор просто подрасчувствовался. Или Вы его успокойте или я его пошлю просто матом. Я зашел попросить совета, а какой-то модератор испортил мне весь день своей ошибкой.

**UPD:**

Ссылка на удаленный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472822/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-spa-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8) (доступен только для пользователей с высокой репутацией).

Comment: Вы вызвали модератора. Он пришел, удалил сообщения, в которых вы его зовете и начал с вами общаться. Все логично: комментарии не место для дискуссий, потерявшие актуальность сообщения всегда удаляются.

Comment: Вопрос-то покажите, по которому был конфликт.

Comment: @shatal, Кстати, а почему вы backbone.js не добавили в метки? Или ember.js? Или еще десяток других фреймворков, позволяющих построить SPA?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, добавил ссылку в вопрос.

Answer (score 10):

Давайте по-порядку.

Первое. Я не модератор, и не собираюсь им быть.

Второе. У сообщества ru.SO есть определенные правила. Мы используем метки для категоризации контента. Если вопрос имеет прямое отношение к технологии, к вопросу применима метка. Вы же пытаетесь *схитрить* и увеличить "охват аудитории" для своего вопроса. При этом сам вопрос не имеет отношения ни к `angular` ни к `react`. Такое использование является не правильным и должно пресекаться, что я в общем-то и сделал.

Третье. Перечитайте еще раз мои комментарии, а затем свой вопрос еще раз. А теперь подумайте кто и кого пытается оскорбить. Возможно моя позиция кажется вам слишком жесткой, но я действую (по-крайней мере стараюсь) в рамках правил.

Comment: Пол года назад я задал вопрос, типа - существуют ли фраймворки, которые позволяют писать приложения использую только js. Знаете что сделало сообщество? Заминусовали вопрос по самое нехочу и оставили коментрия и ответы в которых меня сравнивали с умолишенным. Никто тогда слова не сказал что им нельзя грубить и что они не правы и последний стек технологий является как раз тем, что я искал. То есть они были и неправы и показали лишь свою глупость.

Comment: И вот теперь Вы на все мои аргументы, которые не в состоянии даже понять, убеждаете меня что я должен ПЕРЕПИСАТЬ свое приложение, чтобы Вы не портили мой вопрос.

Comment: @shatal Вас же никто не заставляет следовать рекомендациям которые Вам дают. не нравится не следуйте

Comment: @shatal, Имелось в виду либо не использование меток совсем, либо изменение вопроса так, чтобы в нем шла речь об использовании фреймворков (читай переписать ваш проект)

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev чего считать, Вы прямо сказали что я должен свой проект переписывать чтобы Вы теги не удаляли. А теперь Вы отмазываетесь оправдывая себя тем, что нужно было все не так понимать.

Comment: @shatal, перечитайте мой комментарий **еще раз**. Я предложил вам **либо** смириться с удалением меток, **либо** переписать проект (заодно изменив вопрос), так, чтобы он использовал angular или react. Собственно это полностью согласуется с правилами ru.SO: метки добавляются только если вопрос имеет отношение к указанным технологиям.

Comment: @shatal, а оправдываться перед вами я считаю бессмысленным. Моя позиция заключается в том, что во-первых должно быть четкое следование правилам сообщества, во-вторых утирать сопли обидчивым новичкам это не основная задача пользователей. ru.SO про вопросы и ответы, а не про раздутое ЧСВ.

Answer (score 9):

В модели Stack Overflow вся информация должна находится в вопросе и ответе. Комментарии нужны лишь для запроса дополнительной информации у автора вопроса или ответа. Ни вопросы, ни ответы не предназначены для выяснения отношений. Конечно же, комментарии также не подходят для ведения диалога не относящегося к тематике вопроса. Именно по этой причине часть ваших комментариев была удалена. Пожалуйста, в следующий раз воспользуйтесь [Метой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) или [чатом](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Система меток Stack Overflow предназначена для удобной фильтрации вопросов и навигации по ним. Если вопрос нельзя отнести к той или иной технологии, не стоит и отмечать его соответствующими метками.

При публикации вопроса, я добавляю метки следующим образом.

1. Выбираю наибольшую область знаний, к которой можно отнести мой вопрос.
2. Добавляю соответствующую метку.
3. Далее, выбираю к какой наибольшей под-области знаний можно отнести вопрос.
4. Добавляю соответствующую метку.
5. Повторяю шаги 3 и 4 до тех пор, пока достаточно точно не опишу ту область знаний, к которой можно отнести вопрос.

Как вы видите, может возникнуть диссонанс в случае, если метки вопроса не соотносятся с содержимым.

В своем вопросе, на сколько я могу судить, вы спрашиваете о решение в общем виде, что подтверждает следующая фраза:

> В тегах указал angularjs и reactjs, но хочу заметить, что вопрос не привязан ни к одному фраймворку

Как результат, внесенные другим участником правки оправданы.

Answer (score 7):

Если вы задаете вопрос, в котором вам всё равно, на наком языке решать задачу, ставьте метку [любой-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba) вместо меток конкретных языков.

Если на вопросе стоит метка конкретного фреймворка, то это сразу означает, что данный фреймворк обязательно присутствует в решении задачи.

> свое и единственное верное видение это проблемы

Насколько я понимаю, для вас это одно видение, а не два разных? В том и проблема.